# How to enable random PIDs on Linux?

Tags: security, process, linux-kernel

I'm currently comparing random PID implementation on OpenBSD, FreeBSD and Linux from security perspective.

As long as OpenBSD and FreeBSD are concerned, my work is done. However, while [the answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66153/how-are-the-processes-in-unix-numbered/66189#66189) states that random PID can be enabled on Linux just thanks to a `sysctl` setting, I was not able to determine which setting it is.

Researches on Internet only lead to patches and discussions rejected in the mainstream Linux kernel, and it does not appear in the [grsecurity](https://grsecurity.net/features.php) features either (and obviously on my Linux boxes PIDs are incremental everywhere, with no `sysctl` parameter name seeming related, and a few searches in the kernel source did not show anything relevant).

Is PID randomization really available on Linux?

Comment: What is the benefit?

Comment: @jordanm: Warm, fuzzy feelings of security.  See the recent discussion about that on the OpenBSD misc list for some perspective.

Comment: @jordanm: That's precisely what I'm investigating ;). For some people it seems to be a mandatory basis for a secure system, for other something useless, and some consider it to be even something negative. Sadly nobody seems to have a concrete [answer on Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88692/pid-randomization-benefits) so I finally had to answer myself with a yet-to-complete answer since I found at least interesting differences in the OpenBSD and FreeBSD approaches, and was therefore curious of the mentioned Linux version of random PIDs (if there is really one).

Comment: @lcd047: I know this discussion very well since I was the guy "trolling" that list by trying to understand and compare the different choices made by different OSes.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf: For Linux, one of the popular kernel patches used to do that at some point.  I recall that patch being grsecurity, but I might be wrong.  I haven't really looked at Linux all that closely in a few years.

Comment: @lcd047: As stated in my message, I've already checked grsecurity official features description and source code with no luck. Digging now deeper in this direction (since I also thought it was there), actually the option used to be there ([adding a `rand_pids` sysctl parameter](https://grsecurity.net/confighelp.php) redefining the [behavior of the get_pid() function](http://justskins.com/forums/why-are-process-ids-204416.html) but it doesn't seem to be here anymore. Does this mean that grsecurity team decided to remove this feature from their patch? Investigations ongoing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PID randomization was never available in the mainstream Linux kernel. Apart from individual initiatives, for several years it was mainly available through [grsecurity](https://grsecurity.net/) kernel patch, however [it was removed in the late 2006](https://grsecurity.net/news.php#grsec2110):

> grsecurity 2.1.10 was released today for Linux 2.4.34 and 2.6.19.2.
>   Changes in this release include:
>
> - Removal of randomized PIDs feature, since it provides no useful additional security and wastes memory with the 2.6 kernel's pid bitmap

This completes [my randomized PID implementation comparison](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88692/do-randomized-pid-bring-more-security) between Linux, OpenBSD and FreeBSD :).

Comment: Old thread, but PID randomization seems to be included in mainline Linux kernels these days. I came here since I wanted to turn it off. ;)