# Large process id on rocky linux 8.5

Tags: linux, process, process-management

I started using rocky linux 8.5, I have added cron to reboot this server everyday. server reboots everyday.
When I start some application on this server the process id I get is very large.
It don't cause any problem to me, but I want understand why the process ids are very large for processes even after machine reboot. As per my understanding when machine restarts the process ids count also resets.

Need help to understand the reason, and solution if it has any solution to avoid this case.

Comment: Please post your crontab

Comment: How large is "very large"?

Comment: @Kusalananda 6 digits number

Comment: @MC68020 crontab entry is
00 06 * * * /sbin/reboot

Comment: Don't you think shutdown -r would better fit ?

Comment: @MC68020 I'll try with shutdown -r.

Comment: @MC68020 why? Nothing wrong with `reboot`, is there?

Comment: @terdon : nothing wrong at all with reboot **as long as the machine is "running normally"**. (even less than if the system is running normally reboot should call shutdown) Considering what OP is telling, I suspect its machine is not running normally when asked to reboot.

Comment: @MC68020 At least on my Arch system and on an Ubuntu Server install I have access to, both `/sbin/reboot` and `/sbin/shutdown` are symlinks to `/sbin/systemctl`. WHat makes you think there will be any difference between the two? I had always assumed that since the advent of `systemd`, `reboot` and `shutdown -r` both simply call `systemctl reboot` which is why I was surprised at your suggestion.

Comment: @terdon : You rightly wrote "*since the advent of systemd*". My init system is openrc and OP did not tell what is their init system. If running systemd then I don't know and OP will have to tell if they are running some PID randomizer and if not… then they will have to suspect some sort of fork bomb somewhere.

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206096/367454

Comment: Well, Rocky Linux is based on RHEL which I think requires systemd, so it seems like a safe bet